# SAMA5D27 U-Boot prints strange characters

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot, microchip, atmel

I'm using an ArrowElectronic Shield96 boad which based on SAMA5D27_SIP.

I was able to build:

- at91bootstrap (4.0.5+gitAUTOINC+8fe4b67188-r0 )
- at91 u-boot (v2022.01-at91+gitAUTOINC+76f7f55e04-r0)
- at91 linux kernel (5.15+gitAUTOINC+5aedde3bc3-r0)
- rootFS

following the steps at https://github.com/ArrowElectronics/meta-sd96 obtaining a .wic image.

After flashed successfully the SDCard with balenaEtcher, I got that the U-boot print strange characters.

```
AT91Bootstrap 4.0.5 (2022-11-09 13:05:42)


SD/MMC: Image: Read file u-boot.bin to 0x23f0000
MMC: ADMA supported
SD: Card Capacity: High or Extended
SD: Specification Version 3.0X
SD/MMC: Done to load image
怘▒怘▒f3▒0▒▒▒▒`?▒▒▒▒?▒▒<f̆▒f?▒▒▒▒f▒f▒f▒
x
▒x
x
▒▒0?3▒x?▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒x
~
▒▒▒▒▒▒f
▒▒▒▒▒▒03`03▒0▒f3▒▒▒ffff▒
▒x▒0fx▒`0▒▒f▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒x
▒▒▒▒fff
▒▒f▒▒▒▒f▒▒▒
...
▒▒Ø▒▒f▒x<x
▒▒▒▒▒▒`<Ø▒▒3▒f3xx0▒▒▒▒▒怘▒怘▒3`?<?`?▒▒▒~<▒▒fÆ▒f<▒???▒03`03▒Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Linux version 5.15.68-linux4microchip-2022.10 (oe-user@oe-host) (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.38.20220708) #1 Wed Nov 9 12:48:42 UTC 2022
CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc051] revision 1 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d
CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIP
```

Then kernel start normally.
Its strange because seems u-boot change serial baudrate. Is it possible?

Going deeper enabling more verbose logs, seems that there is some problem in u-boot-at91 v2022.01 and SAMA5D27.dtsi devices tree.

```
Bound device can0_gclk to slowck
size=40, ptr=4f20, limit=8000: aligned to 20008dc0
size=40, ptr=4f60, limit=8000: aligned to 20008e00
clk_register: name: can1_gclk parent: slowck [0x20004c80]
size=50, ptr=4fb0, limit=8000: 20008e40
Bound device can1_gclk to slowck
master clk is overclock▒怘▒怘▒f3▒0▒▒▒▒`?▒▒▒▒?▒▒<f̆▒f?▒▒▒▒f▒f▒f▒
x
▒x▒x
▒▒`0▒▒▒▒
▒x
▒x
```

Answer (score 0):

The default baudrate for U-Boot is defined by the CONFIG_BAUDRATE configuration variable which defaults to 115200.

The baudrate can be set interactively by changing the baudrate environment variable.

```
setenv baudrate 9600
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes CONFIG_BAUDRATE is set to 115200. I can't prompt on u-boot console. If I stop u-boot start pressing some button, u-boot stops but I cant prompt nothing.